# Create Legend Label for Quad glyph - Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, data-science, bokeh

I have a Quad plot displaying 2 data-sets. I would like to add a legend to the plot, however I am not sure how to do this with the Quad glyph.

Previous examples have used 'legend' however this is now deprecated, and I've tried using
'legend_label' however this is does not work.
My ultimate goal is to use the legend to interactively display both datasets

```
    # Convert dataframe to column data source
    src1 = ColumnDataSource(Merged_Bins)
    src2 = ColumnDataSource(Merged_Bins)

    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Plot Histogram using Bokeh plotting library
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    plot = figure(y_range=Range1d(start=0, end=Max_Histogram_Value),sizing_mode="scale_width",width=3000,height= 600,
                  title= "Histogram Plot",
                  x_axis_label="Time (ms)",
                  y_axis_label="Count",toolbar_location = "below")
    plot.yaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(tick_vals))


    glyph1=Quad(bottom=0, top='Delay1', left='left1',
              right='right1', fill_color='#FF7F00',
              line_color='black', fill_alpha=0.7,line_alpha=0.5,name="Option 2")
              
    glyph1_plot=plot.add_glyph(src1, glyph1)
    glyph2=Quad(bottom=0, top='Delay2', left='left2',
              right='right2', fill_color='#616261',
              line_color='#616261',line_alpha=0.1, fill_alpha=0.1,name="Original Design")
              
    plot.add_glyph(src2, glyph2)

    # Add hover tool for when mouse is over data
    hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Delay Envelope', '@Bin_interval'),('Count', '@Delay1'),('Count Original', '@Delay2')],mode='vline',renderers=[glyph1_plot])
    plot.add_tools(hover1)
    plot.legend.location = "top_left"
    plot.legend.click_policy="hide"
    # Set autohide to true to only show the toolbar when mouse is over plot
    plot.toolbar.autohide = True
    script, div = components(plot)
    show(plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine if you use the `Figure.quad` method instead of manually calling `Figure.add_glyph` with an explicitly created instance of `Quad`. All `legen_*` arguments are parsed by glyph methods of the `Figure` class - the glyph classes themselves do not use them at all.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.quad(-1, 1, 1, -1, legend_label='Hello')
p.quad(1, 3, 3, 1, color='green', legend_label='there')

show(p)
```

Alternatively, if you really need the manual approach for some reason, you can also create a legend manually by creating an instance of the `Legend` class and by adding it to the figure with `Figure.add_layout`.

Also, on an unrelated note - your plot looks like it was created with `vbar` instead of `quad` because all bars seem to have the same width. If so, perhaps using `vbar` would be simpler in your case.